# Javascript vs Python with respect to Python 'map()' function

Tags: javascript, python, functional-programming, sml

In Python there is a function called `map` that allows you to go: `map(someFunction, [x,y,z])` and go on down that list applying the function.  Is there a javascript equivalent to this function?

I am just learning Python now, and although I have been told javascript is functional language, I can see that I have been programming in a non-functional javascript style. As a general rule, can javascript be utilized as a functional language as effectively as Python can? Does it have similar tricks like the `map` function above?

I've also just begun an SML course and am wondering how much of what I learn will be applicable to javascript as well.

Comment: It's called `.map()` and it's a method on the Array prototype.

Comment: Js is object-oriented functional. Instead of `map(f,[])` you do `[].map(f)`. But js is also functional in the sense that just like Python you can implement the function `map(f,[])` in javascript. Map is not what makes Python functional. It's the ability to write the `map` function that makes it functional - it just so happens that the standard library has one provided.

Comment: As a note, python doesn't make a really great functional programming language (for that, look at `lisp`, `scheme`, `haskel`).  It has some capabilities, but -- it's not really optimized for that...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure! JavaScript doesn't have a lot of higher-order functions *built-in*, but `map` is one of the few that *is* built-in:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var incrementedNumbers = numbers.map(function(n) { return n + 1 });
console.log(incrementedNumbers);  // => [2, 3, 4]
```

It might be worthwhile to note that `map` hasn't been around forever, so some rather old browsers might not have it, but it's easy enough to implement a shim yourself.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FNew_in_JavaScript%2F1.6#Array_extras

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#map) which adds tons of nice functionalists with only 4k size.

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
//=> [3, 6, 9]
```