# How can I port this "one-line for loop" from Python to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm not sure about the terminology used (I think it's called "lambda" or something like that), so I cannot do a proper search.

The following line in Python:

```
 a, b, c, d, e = [SomeFunc(x) for x in arr]
```

How can I do the same in Javascript?

I have this to begin with:

```
let [a, b, c, d, e] = arr;
```

But I still need to call `SomeFunc` on every element in `arr`.

Comment: It is called a list comprehension, and javascript has no such thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851002/javascript-vs-python-with-respect-to-python-map-function

Comment: Map over the array items.
 `let [a, b, c, d, e] = arr.map(someFunc);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript vs Python with respect to Python 'map()' function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851002/javascript-vs-python-with-respect-to-python-map-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A close approximation would be to use the array method [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It uses a function to perform an operation on each array element, and returns a new array of the same length.

```js
const add2 = (el) => el + 2;

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let [a, b, c, d, e] = arr.map(add2);

console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Be careful when you use array destructuring to ensure that you're destructuring the right number of elements for the returned array.

Comment: I'd be careful with the destructuring just because you might unknowingly leave off elements of the array.

Comment: Thanks. I added a note to that effect to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's called .map() in JavaScript and you'd use it like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4].map(someFunc);
```

and someFunc would be defined somewhere else, maybe:

```
function someFunc(x){ return ++x };
//or es6
let someFunc = x => ++x;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use map in this case

```
function functionF(x){return x}

let [a, b, c, d, e] = arr.map(functionF);
```

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk).

These types of functions are ideal for quick, one-time calculations.  The javascript equivalent is the `map()` function.  For your specific case, the syntax would be

```
    let arr = some_array.map(x => {
        return SomeFunc(x);
    });
```

For example, the statement

```
    let arr = [1, 2, 8].map(num => {
        return num * 2;
    });
```

will assign the list `[2, 4, 16]` to the variable `arr`.

Hope that helps!